# Solving the PDE $x_{1}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}}+x_{2}\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_{2}}=e^{f(x_{1},x_{2})}-\alpha.$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

This post is closely related to [Dirichlet to Neumann operator in the unit ball with Fourier Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571853/dirichlet-to-neumann-operator-in-the-unit-ball-with-fourier-analysis).

I have transformed the exercise in the post above into a problem of finding solution of PDE:$$x_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + x_2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = e^{f(x_1,x_2)}-\alpha \text{ for } \alpha>0.$$

This is an exercise in Fourier analysis, so I am not prepared too many knowledge in differential equation.

There are two hints:

> 1. Use the Fourier Expansion; 2. Separate the argument into $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$.

However... I don't have any idea about how to solve this..

Any idea? Thank you!

**Edit:**

In the link above,  it suggested that if $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$, then $f=\log\alpha$, and asked the reader to further discover what happens if $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$.

So if $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$, we have $$x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}+x_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}=0 \text{??}$$

**Edit 2:**

Below is how I convert the exercise in the link above to this PDE:

Within the context of this exercise, we have the coinciding solution of the Dirichlet problem $$\Delta u=0 \text{ on } B_1$$ $$u=f \text{ on } \partial B_1 =\mathbb{S}^1$$ and of the Neumann problem $$\Delta u=0 \text{ on } B_1$$ $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=e^f-\alpha \text{ on } \partial B_1=\mathbb{S}^1,$$
where $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}= \nabla u\cdot \nu$ is the normal derivative of $u$ at the boundary with respect to the unit outer normal direction $\nu$.

Now, note that for a point $(x_1,x_2)\in\partial B_1 = \mathbb{S}^1$, we always have $\nu=(x_1,x_2)$. Also, by the solution of the Dirichlet problem, we know that $u=f$ on $\partial B_1=\mathbb{S}^1$, and thus on the boundary we have $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu} = \nabla u\cdot \nu=x_1\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1} + x_2 \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_2} = x_1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + x_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2},$$ but the boundary condition of Neumann problem is $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}=e^{f}-\alpha,$$ and thus we have $$x_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + x_2\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = e^{f(x_1,x_2)}-\alpha.$$

**Edit 3: (initial value)**

As "Ninad" pointed out, we need to an initial value to decide what is $C(t).$ And I believe perhaps the initial value is related to whether $\alpha$ is natural or not.

The exercise does not give what happens if $\theta=0$.

However, I missed one conditiona that $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{S}^1)$, a infinity smooth $2\pi-$periodic function.

I don't know if this helps to provide us the initial value.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, if $f = \log \alpha$ and $\alpha$ is independent of the $x_{i}$ then you have $\partial f/\partial x_{i} = \partial \log \alpha/\partial x_{i} = 0$ and the PDE is satisfied, irrespective of the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: @mattos you are correct. but this argument applies to all $\alpha>0$ right? We don't really need $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Can I ask what book this is from?

Comment: @mattos I don't know. this is an exercise given in class, but not a homework.

Comment: @mattos I think given the answer provided by "Ninad", perhaps the initial value is different when $\alpha$ different? you see. apply his answer with initial condition $C(\theta)=0$ and $r=1$ (in the unit ball), we have $f=\log\alpha$ which supposes to be the answer in the case of $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: The boundary function $f$ is only defined on the unit circle, there is no way to know a directional derivative in normal direction. The PDE you are examining is only valid on the boundary, not in inner points of the disk. It makes no sense to extend it there, as you already have the Poisson equation there to satisfy.

Comment: @LutzLehmann is there a way to solve the problem you pointed out by modifying a little bit of the proof?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use polar coordinates

$$x_1 = r\cos\theta$$

$$x_2 = r\sin\theta$$

to convert the PDE into an ODE since

$$x_1\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + x_2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} = r\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$$

giving us the equation

$$r\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = e^{f} - \alpha$$

which we can solve using separation of variables

$$ \frac{dr}{r} = \frac{df}{e^f-\alpha} = \frac{e^{-f}df}{1-\alpha e^{-f}} $$

$$\implies \log r + C(\theta) = \frac{1}{\alpha} \log| 1 - \alpha e^{-f} |$$

$$\implies f = \log\left(\frac{\alpha}{1-C(\theta)r^\alpha}\right)$$

If you have any initial conditions, you can apply them in clever ways in order to figure out what $C(\theta)$ has to be.

---

$\textbf{EDIT}:$ Using the fact that $f$ has a harmonic extension, we can use the polar coordinates Laplacian:

$$\Delta u = \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}$$
to see what functions satisfy the harmonic condition.

$$\Delta f = \frac{\alpha^2 C(\theta) r^{\alpha -2}}{(1-C(\theta)r^\alpha)^2} + \frac{C''(\theta)r^{\alpha-2}}{1-C(\theta)r^\alpha} + \frac{(C'(\theta))^2r^{2\alpha - 2}}{(1-C(\theta)r^\alpha)^2} = 0$$

$$\implies \alpha^2 C(\theta) + C''(\theta) +\left[(C'(\theta))^2 - C(\theta)C''(\theta)\right] r^\alpha  = 0$$

giving two ODEs that need to be simultaneously satisfied. Looking only at the first one, we have that

$$C''(\theta) + \alpha^2C(\theta) = 0 \implies C(\theta) = A\cos(\alpha\theta) + B\sin(\alpha\theta) $$

but notice that $C$ only has a nontrivial $2\pi$-periodic solution if $\alpha$ is an integer. Thus for noninteger $\alpha$ we can conclude that

$$C(\theta) = 0 \implies f = \log \alpha$$

For integer $\alpha$, plug and chug gives us the following equation:

$$(C'(\theta))^2 - C(\theta)C''(\theta) = 0 \implies \alpha^2 (A^2+B^2) = 0$$

which again gives us the trivial solution, which doesn't seem to be what your question implies happens.

Comment: Your solution is really interesting!!

Comment: I missed one condition that $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{S}^{1})$, a $2\pi-$periodic infinity differentiable function. Does this gives us any information about the initial value?

Comment: I think the initial value is related to whether $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ or not. Since if I make $C(\theta)=0$ and $r\nearrow 1$, then $f=\log\alpha$, which is the answer when $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$, suggested by the link

Comment: @JacobsonRadical feel free to check the progress I've made now.

Comment: WOW!!!!!!! You are the king of PDE!!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much. You are right. when $\alpha$ is not the integer, $f=\log\alpha$. This is what the exercise suggested.

Comment: I am gonna open a bounty to reward your answer. This is really a great answer!

Comment: I have only a small question. what makes you say that $C$ only has one non-trivial $2\pi-$periodic solution if $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$, and thus if $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$, $C(\theta)=0$? What is the logic here? and why $\alpha^{2}(A^{2}+B^{2})=0$ gives us the trivial solution? What do you mean the trivial solution?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Thank you for your kind words!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical To address your questions, the first one is $0$ because $\cos(\alpha \theta)$ is not $2\pi$ periodic if $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Z}$. The second, trivial means $C=0$ since that equation implies either $\alpha = 0$ or $A=B=0$, but the first is an impossibility with the work we did earlier.

Comment: Okay. I get it. So the final answer would be $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}$ or $\alpha\notin\mathbb{N}$ gives the same answer. This is fine since the exercise does not say this situation is not possible. It just asks me to think the different case, but they could be the same thing. Thank you so much!

Comment: I can only open a bounty in two days. so I will open it the day after tomorrow. Thank you so much. This is an inspiring and really brilliant answer! I am really excited!!

Answer (score 2):

$$x_1\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} + x_2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = e^{f(x_1,x_2)}-\alpha \tag 1$$
Of course, solving in polar system simplifies the calculus. But it it is not necessary.

The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{dx_2}{x_2}=\frac{df}{e^f-\alpha}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{dx_2}{x_2}$ :
$$\frac{x_2}{x_1}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx_1}{x_1}=\frac{df}{e^f-\alpha}$ :
$$x_1^{-\alpha}\left(1-\alpha e^{-f} \right)=c_2$$
The general solution expressed on the form of implicite equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$x_1^{-\alpha}\left(1-\alpha e^{-f} \right)=F\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function, to be determined according to some boundary condition.

Solving for $f$ leads to :
$$\boxed{f(x_1,x_2)=\ln|\alpha|-\ln\left|1-x_1^{\alpha}F\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right) \right|} \tag 2$$

It is easy to differentiate Eq.$(2)$ for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$ . Then putting them into Eq.$(1)$ and checking the equality proves that $(2)$ is solution of $(1)$.

Note that the particular case $F=0$ gives the trivial solution $f=\ln|\alpha|$

Note :

Since $F$ is an arbitrary function they are an infinity of equivalent forms of equations to express the solution. For example :
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\ln|\alpha|-\ln\left|1-x_2^{\alpha}G\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2}\right) \right|$$ 
with arbitrary function $G$, related to arbitrary function $F$ through : $G(X)=X^{\alpha}F(1/X)$

Note :

In polar coordinates $\quad\begin{cases}x_1=\rho\cos{\theta}\\x_2=\rho\sin{\theta}\end{cases}$

$f(\rho,\theta)=\ln|\alpha|-\ln\left|1-\rho^{\alpha}\cos^{\alpha}(\theta)F\left(\cot(\theta)\right) \right|$
$$f(\rho,\theta)=\ln|\alpha|-\ln\left|1-\rho^{\alpha}H(\theta) \right|$$
where $H$ is an arbitrary function. If you want to have an example of smooth periodic solution on circle of radius $\rho$ ,  choose the function $H$ so that $H$ be periodic and $\big|\rho^{\alpha}H(\theta)\big|<1.$

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice answer!

Comment: Note: The first order PDE is only valid on the boundary as boundary condition for the Poisson equation in the interior of the disk. The solution via characteristic curves is not valid.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann. Forget the way leading to the result $$f(x_1,x_2)=\ln|\alpha|-\ln\left|1-x_1^{\alpha}F\left(\frac{x_2}{x_1}\right) \right|$$. Just check it in putting the result into the PDE. You see that the result is valid. Doesnt matter other considerations. By the way, the result is exactly the same as the Ninad Munshi's result witn notations : $C(\theta)=H(\theta)$.

Comment: Yes, it is a solution, but to the wrong problem. The original question linked in this question is much clearer on that. There the solution has to be a harmonic function where only the normal derivative at the boundary is bound by the given equation.

Comment: OK. In fact my answer was to the first edition of the present question, not to the linked question, mainely to give the general solution of the PDE.